# Converting JSON Format String to XML String throws an Exception

Tags: android, xml, json

I am trying for a long time to find a solution about the following problem that I am facing. I get a special json format string from my Database through a **Http Request** as follows:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n  
          <resources>
          <string> name=\"Test.Company\">Company</string>\r\n  
          <string> name=\"Test.Point\">Point</string>\r\n  
          </resources>"
```

A format as shown above contains only a string daten type.This format must be used as an XML file for an Android application. The Responed data from server is working properly. 
The main point is to convert this **special** jsonformat to **XML**. 
I am using the following code for convertion to XML as follows:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonStr_responded_from_server"); // throws an exception  **of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

String xml = XML.toString(jsonObject);
```

Did anyone has similar problem???

Answer (score 0):

your server returns the normal string. because json object should be in {your object} format.example **json object is {"user":"uservalues","empcode":"emp0041"}**. but your string returned from server not in the format it will throws the error.  [have a look on this link](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

```
String xml = jsonStr_responded_from_server;//string xml returns from server. here no need json object
```

Comment: you are right that the json responded from the server should be in the format you mentioned above. Although in my case the Json format must be returned from the serve as a shown in my Question. Therefore i am facing with an exception.

Comment: then you can assign the jsonStr_responded_from_server to the xml, why you are making json object ? then again making json.tostring()

Comment: Assiging the **jsonStr_responded_from_server** directly to the xml throws an error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/XML**. The data **json_responded_server** remains also after the response the same as shown in my first post. Anyway the json format responded from the server is of a special case. I worked with json format where the `{ [] }` were present.  This is a special case for me.

Comment: `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<resources>\r\n  
<string name=\"Test.Company\">Company</string>\r\n  
<string name=\"Test.Point\">Point</string>\r\n  
<string name=\"Test.Message\">Messages.</string>\r\n  
<string name=\"Test.Error\">Erro</string>\r\n </resources>" ` 
I get a file with many information in a json format. The information  above show only how my string format responded from server looks like.

Comment: I want this json string format to convert to an string format saved in **XML** File

Comment: please post your full code where you are getting noclassdeffound exception

Comment: `try {JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr_responded_from_server); // this trows an exception that string can not be converted to JSONObject
String xml = XML.toString(jsonObj);} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }`
**2.methode**
`String xml = XML.toString(jsonStr_responded_from_server)` // throws an error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/XML** Even that org.json library is inserted in the project.

Comment: Unfortunatelly 'string xml = jsonStr_responded_from_server` shows the following components: '"` and `\r\n`. And the main reason is that I want to have my data in a string format. Which I will save afterthat in an **XML** file.

Comment: it will display in debug but in file it will not be there

Comment: I tried it but again shows the same as depicted on my first post. This means a JsonFormat String remains the same including `"` and `\r\n`. It is very interesing that using `new JSONObject(jsonStr_responded_from_server)` removew the `"` and `\r\n` but aftarthat throws an excpetion.